# Picture saving in emulator but not on device

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-camera

I am using the following code to save/ load my picture

```
 OnCreate(){
  super.onCreate();
  setContentView(...)
 ....
  setImage();   

  }
 protected void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   setImage();  
   }


protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
   setImage();
```

}

```
protected void onPostResume(){
   super.onPostResume();
   setImage();
```

}

```
private void setImage(){
    if(loadPicture(getIntent().getStringExtra("position"),bitmap ) != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          imageView.setImageBitmap(loadPicture(getIntent().getStringExtra("position"), bitmap));
    }
}
private void takePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

private void savePicture(String filename, Bitmap b, Context ctx){
    try {
           ObjectOutputStream bos;
           FileOutputStream out;// = new FileOutputStream(filename);
           out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
           bos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
           b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
          if(b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos) == true)
              Toast.makeText(this, "returned true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          bos.flush();
        //  bos.close();
          out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private Bitmap loadPicture(String filename, Bitmap b){
    //Drawable myImage = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream bis = null;
        try {
            bis = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // myImage = Drawable.createFromStream(ois, filename);
         b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        try {
            //bis.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return myImage;
    return b;

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            try {
                bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, false));
                //previos imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                savePicture(getIntent().getStringExtra("position"), bitmap,
                        getApplicationContext());

                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();



            }
```

This works perfectly for saving the image in the emulator(the sample image, that is), but it doesn't work in the real phone. After I take the image and press the 'OK" icon on the phone, there is a blank screen for about 20 secs. and then it crashes.

Comment: Can you paste the logcat exception stack?

Comment: How do I retrieve the logcat stack since it works fine on the emulator... on the device, I suspect it's a timeout since i feel like the app crashes after an extended period of time... what could be causing this? I think it has something to do with the way I am saving the file

Comment: You can connect your IDE to your device using a usb cable and enable debugging on device. See [http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: so the problem was Suspended (exception OutOfMemoryError). I confirmed that the image file was too big by capturing with megapixel 1 rather than 5. how do I fix this and allow user to take even a high-res picture? @Justin, could you post some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try some of the solutions provided here

- [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)

Comment: I'm sorry for not updating you, but I solved this issue sometime earlier using the same link you provided me. Great answer, as this was the solution to my problem!