# taking and saving picture android camera : the picture is not saved on my device

Tags: android, android-camera, save

I'd like to have a simple app that takes a picture and saves it in the Gallery, as shown here : http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

I tested the app on my device (2.1), i took the picture, they asked me to click on "ok", but the picture is not saved in the Gallery, do you know why? and how i could know where the error comes from? (the emulator does not have any "sd card", so i cannot really debug the project). Also, what's the difference between this technique and the one  with `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);` : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#modifying ?

Also, i could try this solution : [Picture saving in emulator but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880806/picture-saving-in-emulator-but-not-on-device) but i was wondering why the code does not work on my device..?

```
package pack.one;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TestPictureActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";
    Intent takePictureIntent;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dispatchTakePictureIntent(11);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
        takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        try {
            handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) throws IOException {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlayout, null);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.V);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);

        File f = createImageFile();
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));

        galleryAddPic();
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(0));
        String imageFileName = timeStamp + "_";
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, 
            JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, 
            null //default location for temporary files
        );
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
}
```

edit: in case someone wants to test the app, i just added these 2 lines in the manifest :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

edit 2 : i actually have the picture in the "phone", when i plug the device to my computer, i can see a new picture file, with the right name, but it's empty, so i cannot open it. Plus, nothing appears in my gallery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try addding this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: thanks Seshu Vinay, still not working, i edited my post above: nothing appears in Gallery, but i can see that a file has been put in the phone, even if i cannot open this file, because it's "empty"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in your AndroidManafest.xml file?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: thanks Bill, i didn't put this line, i reinstalled the app with this line, but the picture is still not displayed in my gallery...